# I'm wanting to add a second designer form to my pre-existing form

Tags: c#, designer

Should I go about this as just making another form.cs? Or is there a way that I could make it so I have a second Designer.cs

[image]

Is it possible to have a second Designer in the same cs as another designer? I just don't want to have 4 different .cs for each of my main cs.

Let me know if this isn't clear enough to see what I'm trying to do, and I'll try to get more detail

Comment: I think you might need to explain why you feel you need another designer for the same form..

Comment: Designer.cs is a partial class of the form.cs so if you add another one and you mark it as partial every control defined there will show up as well

Comment: Just so it's not as cluttered in my solution explorer really the only reason. I'm fine with making more if I need to, just something I thought would make it look better on the coder end @BugFinder

It would also eliminate the need for needing a whole seperate partial class.